# behat 3 - Using constructor breaks output

Tags: behat

I followed the tutorial on http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/quick_intro_pt1.html.
But when I have implemented the feature and running behat it is said in the tutorial that I should get an error: "Fatal error: Class 'Shelf' not found."
I did not get that error. Only the output of the user story:

$ vendor/bin/behat

Feature: Product basket
  In order to buy products
  As a customer
  I need to be able to put interesting products into a basket

Rules:
  - VAT is 20%
  - Delivery for basket under £10 is £3
  - Delivery for basket over £10 is £2

```
class FeatureContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    private $shelf;
    private $basket;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shelf = new Shelf();
        $this->basket = new Basket($this->shelf);
    }


    /**
     * @Given there is a :product, which costs £:price
     */
    public function thereIsAWhichCostsPs($product, $price)
    {
        $this->shelf->setProductPrice($product, floatval($price));
    }
```

It looks like, when I am using a constructor this happening and the output of behat is just the user story but not the tests.
Even if I put an exit() in the function the exit() is not happening.
I have tried this with different projects in PHPStorm. It is always the same.

I am wondering how I could get the expectedt error: "Fatal error: Class 'Shelf' not found."
I am using behat 3.0.14: I have used composer to install it.

Comment: I have found the solution. It was because of the PHP version.

Comment: I have found the solution. It was because of the PHP version.

I am using OSX 10.10 and I have set up MAMP as webserver. I have removed the MAMP directory from my $PATH and set standard /usr/bin/php. Also I set this PHP path when installing behat with PhpStorm with composer. Now I got the expected error message.